# Cannot add PPA Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

Tags: php, ubuntu, migration, php-5.6, php-5.4

I 'm using ubuntu 12.04 and i want to upgrade my php version from 5.4 to 5.6

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

i install the certificat using these command line

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

. but i still have the sae issue . could someone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) is past the end-of-life period and as such many ppas have removed packages for precise.  Launchpad also does not allow upload of packages to end-of-lifed distributions.

At the time, it looks like the ondrej/php ppa only supports 14.04, 16.04, 17.10, and 18.04.

Their homepage states:

> Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

I'd suggest upgrading your distribution to something more recent than precise (now 6 years old).

Comment: even i upgrade to 14.04 i still have the same issue

Comment: Show `lsb_release -a` in your original post?